# How to get the full path of current target file using NLog at runtime in .NET Core 7?

Tags: nlog, asp.net-core-6.0

I have an application in .NET Core Console that is working fine in .NET Core 6. I am testing the conversion of this app in the newly released .NET Core 7 and all works fine except the part where I dynamically get the path of the NLog target.

My NLog.config is like this:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
> <nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
>   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>   autoReload="true"
>   internalLogLevel="Warn"
>   internalLogFile="internal-CimplDataLoader.log">
>   
> <extensions>
>     <add assembly="NLog.Extensions.Logging" />
> </extensions>
>
> <targets>
>   <target xsi:type="File" name="allfile" fileName="${shortdate}.log"
>               layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId.Id}|${logger}|${uppercase:${level}}|${message} ${exception}"
>               keepFileOpen="false"/>
> </targets>
>
> <rules>
>   <!--All logs, including from Microsoft-->
>   <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="allfile" />
> </rules>
> </nlog>
> ```

The code that works in .NET Core 6:

```
    if (LogManager.Configuration != null)
    {
        Target target = LogManager.Configuration.FindTargetByName("allfile");
        var logEventInfo = new LogEventInfo { TimeStamp = DateTime.Now };
        FileTarget? fileTarget;

        // Unwrap the target if necessary.
        if (target is not WrapperTargetBase wrapperTarget)
            fileTarget = target as FileTarget;
        else
            fileTarget = wrapperTarget.WrappedTarget as FileTarget;

        if (fileTarget != null)
        {
            string fileName = fileTarget.FileName.Render(logEventInfo);
            string LogPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName)!;

            /* Work with LogPath */
        }
        else
        {
            _logger.LogError("Unable to get NLog \"allfile\" base directory.");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        _logger.LogError("Unable to read NLog configuration.");
    }
```

This same code in .NET Core 7 fails because `LogManager.Configuration` is always null. Is there any way I can still dynamically get the path in .NET Core 7?

Comment: Think the NLog.config is not being loaded. Maybe forgot to enable "Copy if newer" ? Remember not to use the nuget-package [NLog.config](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Config). If the NLog.config is deployed correctly to the bin-folder, then consider enabling [NLog InternalLogger](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging) from code to see why it doesn't load.

Comment: Damn!! I feel stupid. When I switch to .NET 7 it created new folders and, nlog.config was not copied over. As soon as nlog.config was present in the folder, code started to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

NLog.config was not present, hence the failure. This was due to the switch from .NET 6 to .NET 7 and nlog.config property "Copy To Output Directory" set to "Do not copy".